# der(der(A)) and der(A)

Tags: real-analysis, clustering

I have a question about cluster points that would like to ask you, this question is one of the exercises in my textbook.

**Question**: If $A$ is any subset of $R^d$, then $der(der($A$))$ is the set of all cluster points of $der$ ($A$)

(a) Given an example of a subset $A$ of $R$ for which der(der($A$))= empty set and der(A) is not empty

(b) Given an example of a suset $A$ of $R$ for which der(der($A$)) = der($A$)

(c)Given an example of a subset $A$ of $R$ for which empty set does not equal to $der(der($A$))$ does not equal to der($A$)

(d) Show that, if $A$ is a nonempty subset of $R^d$, then der(der($A$)) is a subset of der($A$).

*der($A$) is defined as the set of cluster points of $A$, and the definition for cluster point is that for all $r$>0, there exist a punctured ball of radius $r$ such that the intersection of this punctured ball and the set A is not empty.*

My ideas:

(a) I am thinking about an interval, for example [-1,0] and we only consider about the rational number in betwee. I am stuck here because I am not sure whether the cluster point for tational number is empty or non-empty.

(b) I am thinking about an interval [-1,1 ]as well, but this time we consider all the real numbers in between. All the numbers within this interval are cluster points and the set of all cluster points of der ($A$) are also all the points of this interval.

(c) I haven't come up anything for this one yet, so any hints would be really appreciated.

(d) for the proof part, I am thinking that maybe i need to start by listing the definitions of cluster points.

Any suggestions and help would be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Let me know if the text is not readable.

Fishing

Comment: What does der($A$) mean?

Comment: it means the cluster points of subset A.

Comment: Your "refers to" is wrong here; I have edited it to make sense. (Also, your "cluster point" is usually called a "limit point".)

Comment: Now that's sorted out, I looked at the question, and it's obvious that (a) and (d) can't both be right!

Comment: Is cluster point the same as limit point? They refer to two different things according to my textbook

Comment: @user311290 In Hausdorff spaces (more generally in $T_1$-spaces), cluster points and limit points of a set coincide. The difference only becomes visible in spaces that aren't $T_1$. (If you don't know what I'm talking about, just note that in principle these are different concepts, but for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ they coincide.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your explanation! so for $R^d$, I just treat limit point and cluster point as the same thing?

Comment: Yes, but stay aware of the fact that in principle, these are different concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (a), look for a set $A$ with just one limit point.
Your (b) is correct.
For (c), try to combine (a) and (b).
I can't make sense of (d).

Comment: (d) makes sense, it just happens to be false.

Comment: I had a typo for (d), not der(der(A)) = der (A), it is der(der(A)) is a subset of der (A)